# Looking for an example of a rationally indifferent cycle.

Tags: complex-analysis, rational-functions, complex-dynamics

Let  $p \in \mathbb {c} $ be a period point of a rational function $R$ i.e. it is a fixed point for an Iterate $R^n $. If $(R^n)'(p)=e^{2\pi i t} $ for some $t \in \mathbb {Q} $ then p is called rational indifferent. For a minimal $n $, $(p,R(p),R^2 (p),...,R^{n-1}(p))$ is then called rational indifferent cycle.( Are my assumption true?) Now I am looking for some examples of them, preferably cycles with order $>1$. Since I already found $R(z)=e^{2 \pi i t }(z+z^2) $ which has a rational indifferent fixpoint in the origin. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $t\in\Bbb Q$, $t\ne0,1$ and
$$
R_t(z)=z^2+\frac14\,e^{2\pi it}-1.
$$
Then
$$
p_\pm=\frac{1}{2} \left(-1\pm\sqrt{1-e^{2 i \pi  t}}\right)
$$
are periodic of period $2$ and $(R^{(2)})'(p_\pm)=e^{2 i \pi  t}$.

Note that these points $t = \frac14\,e^{2\pi it}-1$ all lie on the circle of radius $1/4$ centered at the point $c=-1$. This is exactly the boundary of the period 2 disk in the Mandelbrot set. If, for example, we set $t=3/4$, we obtain $z^2-1+i/4$ as shown in yellow below:

[image]

More generally, the rational values of $t$ produce points where a smaller bulb is attached. The Julia set for this value of $c$ looks like so:

[image]

The red dots form an orbit of period 2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there maybe a similary simple example for $deg R>1$. I am especially asking in regard to the theorem that all these rationally indifferent cycles are in the Julia Set

Comment: I have included examples of degree $2$ in the answer.

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Parabolic_Julia_set_from_period_2_thru_internal_angle_1_over_4.png

Comment: @Julián Aguirre: Is it t = 1/4 not 3/4 ?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [program Mandel](http://www.mndynamics.com/indexp.html) for it:

- choose your function
- on the parameter plane click inside component
- choose t ( = internal angle = rotation number) : Menu/Points/bifurcation
- then go to dynamic plane
- choose periodic point ( it is what you are looking for)

See also parabolic Julia sets:

- [images and src code](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Parabolic_Julia_sets)
- [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/parabolic)

HTH